# Is there a more convenient way to find out what keys do in org-agenda than looking it up or just pressing them?

Tags: key-bindings, org-agenda, help

Sometimes just pressing keys until one does what I want works, but this feels rather unelegant. Is there an easier way of finding out what keys do what?

Comment: I'm confused by this question (not least by the notion of "just pressing keys until one does what I want"), but do you want `C-h m` ? (which works in any buffer); or `C-h i g (org)Agenda commands` ? (to read the relevant node in the manual); or are you looking for something else? (in which case please explain).

Answer (score 1):

When you're in the agenda buffer try `C-h m` which should give an overview of the current mode, show which commands are available and list their keybindings.

There are a few other ways to access the built in documentation (as found in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Help-Summary.html)) that you might want to explore.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `kc-mode` or `kc-auto-mode`, from library [**Key See**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeySee) (code: [**`keysee.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/keysee.el)). (It, in turn, requires library [Sortie](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Sortie) ([`sortie.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/sortie.el)).

   - **`kc-mode`** shows you, *on demand*, at any time, all of the keys you can use then, along with the commands they are bound to.
   - **`kc-auto-mode`** does the same as `kc-mode`, but it also shows you *automatically* all of the keys you can use after you use a prefix key (e.g. `C-x`), along with their commands.
2. Even better: use **Icicles** [key completion](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Key_Completion). (*Key See* behavior is a simplified version of this.) In addition to what KC shows you, you can immediately get complete help on any key/command shown - its full doc string is shown in buffer `*Help*`.